# QApplication and handling X server shutdown

Tags: qt, x11

I have a Qt application that runs on a linux machine that displays UI windows on a Windows machine running an X server.  There's a strong possibility that the users of my application will logout of Windows or kill the X server without quitting my application first.

Is there a way to handle the unexpected shutdown of the X server, so that the application can gracefully shutdown, save stored data, etc?  So far I've tried tying QApplication's aboutToQuit signal to a slot in my app, plus catching all exceptions in main.  Neither worked as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to attempt to handle it via [signal handling](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/csignal/signal/)

depending on how application is being killed by the OS, exiting gracefully may or may not be possible at all.

Comment: I'm not sure the X server dying would throw any sort of signal though.  It's strange because the QApplication loop does die in some way (or the app would continue running), it just doesn't seem to notify anything that it's dying.

Comment: This behavior consistent with your application being sent something like a SIGTERM, it would interrupt execution of your program without giving it a chance to do anything about it. I'd throw in a signal handler and see if you're app is getting anything that it can respond to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe this `QCoreApplication::aboutToQuit()` signal can help you.

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that I tried that already.  The signal never fires as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

If connection with the X server is lost then `libX11` inside the application calls `_XIOError()` function that calls `_XDefaultError` handler that calls `exit()`. It is possible to override that with a custom handler:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

static int handler(Display *dpy)
{
    /* 
     * cleanup
     * ...
     */

    exit(1);
    return 0;
}

...

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    XSetIOErrorHandler(handler);
    ...
```

It's better to still call `exit()` in the handler because Qt will segfault anyway without a proper X connection.